# Why is my function not a function in test environment

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I do not understand why my code works locally and not in my test environment. It says that my function is not a function. Locally it even prints out a function, when I console.log it out. Could it be some naming mapping that have gone wrong? I can not publish my code, I am just asking if it is an easy answer to this.

I think the reason is something in the bundling process

Thank you

Comment: please share more code

Comment: We cannot possibly help without seeing your code. You can surely obfuscate sensitive data. In any case, client-side JavaScript cannot be protected.

Comment: If you can't publish the code, you could write some example that also shows the same problem

Answer (score 1):

Did you compile your react code and uploaded to your test environment?
I think it might be because you didn't compile properly or you're using ES6 on the server that does not support it. 
Anyway it would be always helpful share the link after uploaded your code.

Comment: Thank you. I will look into that!